# Django 1.4 - Redirect to Non-HTTP urls

Tags: python, django, url, redirect, django-1.4

We have a view which redirects to a Non-HTTP url scheme. Its used in an iOS app. But since we have upgraded to Django1.4 we are getting a crash when this redirect code is executed. It crashes with

> SuspeciousOperation at /myyrlscheme/
>
> Unsafe redirect to URL with scheme appdev:

Following is the code:

```
if acode and acode.has_key('access_token'):
    if DOMAIN == 'dev.mywebsite.com':
        return HttpResponseRedirect('appdev://fbconnect?token=%s'%(acode['access_token']))
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('app://fbconnect?token=%s'%(acode['access_token']))
```

I can understand why this crashes as `HttpResponseRedirect` expects a `HTTP(s)` url scheme. How do I tell Django that this is a safe url and just blindly redirect?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I believe you'll need to have a custom Response object, consider following:

```
response = HttpResponse("", status=302)
response['Location'] = "appdev://..."
return response
```