# Submit a form and execute an a href tag, simultaneously

Tags: html, django, href, forms

Is there any way to `submit` a form and execute an `a href` tag simultaneously?

I need to call `<a href="sms:14085551212?body=Please see this url:[url here]">Send SMS</a>` and the following `form` code together:

```
<form action="{% url 'insert_details' slug=unique %}" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
<input type="hidden" name="unique" value="{{ unique }}">
<input type="submit" name="ok" value="OK">
</form>
```

---

If I successfully do this simultaneously, it allows me to redirect the user to their phone's SMS app with a pre-filled message, while also processing some related code in my `views.py` (it's a Django app, the html will appear in a Django template).

Please note that the client *doesn't support JS*, so alternative solutions involving JS are, and will remain, out of my scope. I'm looking for some ingenuity in accomplishing this task.

**Note:** using an `<a href=""></a>` tag inside `<button type="submit"></button>` doesn't work - it submits the form for me, but I can't seem to get the redirect working.

Comment: Can you just return a [redirect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) in your view?

Comment: That's what I wanted, but it's proving impossible to get right. Here's a separate question I posed for that in case you want to see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35373245/calling-a-special-non-http-url-from-the-form-valid-method-of-a-django-class-ba